# Access to HTML forms via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I get an inputs content in jQuery. Like this option in JavaScript:

```
document.forms["Register"]["userName].value
```

Thanks

Comment: don't you have any id on your inputs? id selectors are better choice.

Comment: @Jai I use name attribute, not ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like :

```
$('form[name="form1"] [name="name"]').val();
```

See example :

http://jsfiddle.net/maddyjolly2112/gfn46ckx/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$('form[name="Register"] [name="userName"]').val();
```

using `.filter()`:

```
$('form[name="Register"] input').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('name') === 'userName'
}).val();
```